# How to attach a "physics box" to a bone

Tags: physics

i'm having a problem

I'm a beginner and i followed a tutorial to add physics to a character.

I created two "physics ball" that deform my model as i wish but these ball do not follow my character as i wish when it's time for animation , they never explain how to do it in Character physics tutorials.

I saw a video in wich the guy (rushing the process without explaining) select the box and a SINGLE bone and then bind them together via a shortcut (can't remember wich, CTRL+P i guess) and i can't reproduce that because

In Object mode > I can select only all the armature and not a single bone
In pose mode> I can't select my "physic box"
In edit mode> I can only select one thing (armature/mesh/ect) and can't touch the others

I tried to parent the box to the bone via the pannels but it did not work at all,terrible results.

It is probably easy and obvious to you,but not for me.

PS: "Hello" is deleted from my messages i do not know why"

Comment: It depends on the type of physics-- rigid body?  Soft body? Cloth?  Please clarify.

Comment: in pose mode I can't select my "physic box" >> you can from the outliner. If you can't from the 3dview is probably because the box is near a bone, so the bone is selected instead.

Comment: It is soft body physics